# Infecting\transmitting value to the adjacent items of list, in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

There is a list of binary values:

```
List<bool> myList = new List<bool>(){true, true, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false};
```

my algorithm aims to convert any false item to true, if they are adjacent to a true value:

```
result = {true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false}
```

My solution works, as you will see. I can do it through two different loops, and then zip two lists:

```
List<bool> firstList = new List<bool>();
List<bool> secondList = new List<bool>();
for(int i=0; i<myList.Count()-1; i++){
  if(myList[i]==true){
    firstList[i]=true;
    firstList[i+1]=true;
  }
}

for(int i=1; i<myList.Count(); i++){
  if(myList[i]==true){
    secondList[i]=true;
    secondList[i-1]=true;
  }
}

List<bool> finalList = firstList.Zip(secondList, (a,b)=>a||b).ToList();
```

However, it doesn't seem to be the best solution since the problem looks very easy. Any idea to do it through one loop or preferably using linq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a Linq approach

Basically it has the same behaviour as your approach - the element self `x`, the previous `.ElementAtOrDefault(i - 1)` or the next `.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1)` element has to be true.

```
List<bool> result = myList.Select((x, i) => x || myList.ElementAtOrDefault(i - 1) || myList.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: why not use aggregate?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in one loop:

```
List<bool> result = myList.Select((b, index) => 
                  b || 
                  (index > 0 && myList[index-1]) || 
                  (index < (myList.Count - 1) && myList[index+1])).ToList();
```

This takes every `b` in your `myList` and checks (via `index`) if this itself or the adjacting values are `true`. Of course we have to check `index` for the list boundaries.

Comment: @Thank you for smart solution. thumps up but if you dont mind, I accept fubo's solution. I like the way he used ElementAtOrDefault method.

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan That's fine, accept the one that fits your needs. The `ElementAtOrDefault()` is indeed nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is particularly readable, but:

```
var indexesToChange = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, myList.Count)
    .Where(n => myList[n]
        || (n-1 >= 0 && myList[n-1])
        || (n+1 < myList.Count && myList[n+1]))
    .ToList();

foreach (var i in indexesToChange)
{
    myList[i] = true;
}
```

This will update the old list.  You could copy to a new list in the `foreach` loop if you don't want to change the old one.